# How to disable Compose key in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have disable compose key by using `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and when I double checked it in `gnome-tweaks` it is already disabled. Like this:

[image]

But the main problem raised when I want to press `Ctrl+Shift+u` the compose key worked unexpectedly.
When I check this attribute in terminal `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-source xkb-options` that says to me: `No such schema “org.gnome.desktop.input-source”`

Really I don't know how to disable that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+U is an ibus keybinding, not gnome's.

https://superuser.com/questions/358749/how-to-disable-ctrlshiftu

This might help you. Sorry for not writing the solution directly.